# Javascript ArrayBuffer to zip

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer, jszip

i'm working with a REST API which sends me a zip file through an octet-stream. I'm trying to retrieve this file with angular4 and while that's going fine i need to transform the incoming ArrayBuffer into a zip file. I've been looking at JsZip but it doesn't seem to offer the functionality i need and i can't seem to figure out what the best way would be.

```
this.issueIdentity('person', 'bk').subscribe((response)=>{
    console.log("sucessfully issued identity to participant", response);
    this.enrollmentData = response.arrayBuffer();
})
```

Help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not setting the correct responsetype in the Angular http client. I now receive a blob which can be used with JsZip.

```
http.post(url,data,{responseType:ResponseContentType.Blob}).subscribe((response)=>{
   response.blob();
})
```